# Error during calling function in smart contract

Tags: solidity, web3.py, python

I have the following contract. When I try to call swap_token function from the RemixIDE, I get the error:

`Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending? execution reverted`I specify the amount of ETH as an argument of the function.
I also tried to call the function using python web3 library using the following code:

```
contract_address = ''
signature = ''
from_address = ''
goerli_url = 'https://goerli.infura.io/v3/'
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(goerli_url))
contract = w3.eth.contract(address = contract_address,abi = abi)
nonce = w3.eth.get_transaction_count(from_address)
tprint('Uniswap project')
print(contract.functions.get_balance().call())
key = contract.functions.swap_token(10000000000000000).buildTransaction({'from':from_address,'nonce':nonce})
tx_code = w3.eth.signTransaction(key,signature)
w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(tx_code.rawTransaction)
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
raise ContractLogicError('execution reverted')
web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted
```

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
contract Uniswap {
    address private constant uniswap_goerli = '0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f';
    address private constant WETH_Goerli = '0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6';
    address private constant ETH_Goerli = '0x7af963cF6D228E564e2A0aA0DdBF06210B38615D';

    function swap_token(uint _amount_to_send) public {
       // uint amount_to_send = _amount_to_send * 1e18;
        IERC20(ETH_Goerli).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this),_amount_to_send);
        IERC20(ETH_Goerli).approve(uniswap_goerli,_amount_to_send);


    }
    function get_balance() public view returns(uint) { 
        return address(this).balance;
    }
```

Could you help and tell me how I should call via Remix and Web3 library?

Comment: Did you approve the contract to pull your `ETH_Goerli` token?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have the token(ETH_Goerli) amount that you are trying to `transferFrom` `msg.sender` (your address) to `address(this)` (smart contract that you deployed).

Also, make sure that `msg.sender` needs to approve the smart contract to transfer ETH_Goerli

you can use EthTx [tx decoder](https://ethtx.info/) to see execution trace